# Curl command not working when trying to run through airflow dags but working separately through local machine

Tags: curl, automation, devops, airflow

I have following dag task:(snippet of only tasks)

```
DAG_START = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1', python_callable=REDIS.set_running, trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS, dag=DAG)



DVT_TASK = BashOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    bash_command=' validation.sh ',
    retries=3,
    retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=5),
    retry_exponential_backoff=True,
    on_failure_callback=task_fail_slack_alert,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    dag=DAG)

DAG_END = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task3',
    python_callable=REDIS.set_success,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    dag=DAG)


#JOB ORDER 1
DVT_TASK.set_upstream(DAG_START)

#JOB_ORDER 2
DAG_END.set_upstream(DVT_TASK)
```

Dag is getting created properly also my validation.sh have a curl command which triggers DVT validation. If I run same curl command through my machine DVT validations getting triggered but when I tried through airflow it is not working.
(I have tried to keep a simple echo command instead of curl command just to check if script is getting executed or not ? so, script ran fine having echo command. For some reason curl command is not getting executed! any help or suggestions appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. In curl command the url which it is hitting was not https that is secure one thats why dag was failing.